# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Messages__Email__3D9E16F4"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe someone can tell me why this is happening. I wrote this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Newmessages 
    @Message_id VARCHAR(20)
    ,@First_name VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Last_name VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Email VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Phone VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Postal_code VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Notification_1 BIT
    ,@Notification_2 BIT
    ,@Own_Pets BIT
    ,@Organization_Id VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Animal_Id VARCHAR(20)
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Messages]
    VALUES (@Message_id, @First_name, @Last_name, @Email, @Phone,
            @Postal_code, @Notification_1, @Notification_2, @Own_Pets,
            @Organization_Id, @Animal_Id)
```

Now I'm trying to check it by inserting:

```
exec Newmessages '64654', 'Kelli', 'Adkins', 'acprthvs.bpuzcnt@gmail.com', '478-6273327', 'SR5 2QF', 'False', 'False', 'False', '91839', '40550'
```

and I get:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Newmessages, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]  > The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Messages__Email__3D9E16F4". The conflict occurred in database "Petfinder", table "dbo.Users", column 'Email'.

Thing is, I checked and I do have the email I'm trying to insert in the `Users` table (which is the error).

Here I checked that it does exist in `dbo.Users`:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is still happening?

Comment: Using the email address as the PK, and therefore needing to duplicate it in another table, isn't the right design choice here. Give the email address a unique ID, and then use that ID as the Primary and Foreign Keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email address you're trying to insert is `acprthvs.bpuzcnt@gma`, which doesn't exist in your table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Newmessages 
    ...
    ,@Email VARCHAR(20)
    ...
```

The email address you'd *like* to enter is 26 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit column list on the INSERT to map the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Messages] (Message_ID,First_Name, Last_name, Email, Phone, ...)

VALUES (
    @Message_id
    ,@First_name
    ,@Last_name
    ,@Email
    ,@Phone
    ,@Postal_code
    ,@Notification_1
    ,@Notification_2
    ,@Own_Pets
    ,@Organization_Id
    ,@Animal_Id
    )
```